# How to show the life bar under units?

Tags: kings-bounty-the-legend

[image: kings bounty pic]

Does anybody know how to show that bar? It's disappeared...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the <kbd>alt</kbd> key to toggle between showing and hiding this information. It also toggles showing the unit's turn in the sequence (that "5" next to the number of units).